# What is wrong with this resource / table?

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-server-express

I have an SQL Express file with a single table People. People has six or seven columns, but no rows. The database is a resource in my Visual Studio 2010 Express project. I am trying to connect with this code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=C:\\someLocation\\someDatabase.mdf; Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True ");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select * from People;", conn);
```

However, I am getting the following error:

`Invalid object name 'People'.`

Based on some casual googling I tried to precede the table name with dbo (dbo.People) but that did not resolve the issue. What might I be doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Here is a screenshot of Visual Studio showing the database, it's structure and content, and its presence in the Solution Explorer:
[image]

Comment: on which line are you getting the error?

Comment: Can you post the exact structure of the table?

Comment: @Adel: If I comment out the line with the `SqlCommand` object then I do not get the error.

Comment: @joshhendo: I could recreaate it by hand in MySQL-style SQL, but I do not see how to run a SQL query on this thing, so I created the table with the wizard. Is there some way to export the structure? Googling I don't see how as this is SQL Express.

Comment: I added a screenshot showing the database. Thanks.

Comment: Any updates or answers found?

Comment: Hi Adel! I just added an answer about five minutes ago! It turns out that I was running into a deliberate limitation in SQL Express, see my answer below. Thank you for your help, this has been very frustrating. I am used to the world of CentOS and MySQL where all the features of the software enabled even for the base versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this query instead and tell us if you see a table with the name People:

```
select TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables where TABLE_TYPE ='BASE TABLE'
```

C# Code example:

```
SqlCommand command = SqlConnection .CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "select TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME as Name from
              INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables where TABLE_TYPE =
              'BASE TABLE'";
connection.Open();
```

Comment: Thank you! That query (in different code) does compile and run, but I don't see any output when going over the command with a SqlDataReader.

Comment: If you don't see any output then your table does not exist, make sure the path to the database is correct, make sure the configuration is correct

Comment: Thank you Adel. The path is certainly correct (incorrect paths give errors) and the table name is correct (copy-paste). What configuration can I check?

Comment: Can you query the database from Visual Studio explorer?

Comment: How does one do that? The context menu items (right click) don't give any options to run a query, nor does anything else. Thanks.

Comment: I used to do it a long time ago but forgot how. You can check this link. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171757.aspx)

Comment: That tool will not query SQL Express databases, only SQL Compact databases. I should mention that I can browse this SQL Express database with SQL Server Management Studio and see the table.

Comment: Try this query `select TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME as Name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables` and post its output plz

Comment: I added a screenshot showing the database. The query that you mention, however, returns no rows! Thanks.

Comment: right click the database in the Database Explorer and open the properties, then copy the connexion string information and check that what you have in the code is the same as the one in the properties

Comment: You said the query returns no rows. This means you are connecting to an empty database!!

Answer (score 0):

For archive diggers and my future self, answering my own question:

I now see that since my project is on a network drive Visual Studio is creating the database inside the project, then silently making a copy in my profile folder (I'm not running as Admin) and using that one. So the database created in the project is not the same database that is shown in the Database Explorer. It seems that this is a limitation of SQL Express, other database types do not have the no-network-drive limitation.

The posible solutions are:

1. Put all projects on the local drive.
2. Run an SQL Server instance on the network drive and access the database through the remote connection.
3. Keep the database on the local drive, outside the project.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like Table `People` is missing from database or not in the Default Schema

Try using Fully Qualified Name (eg. `select * from dbo.People` )

Comment: Thanks, but that is not it. I even mentioned in the OP that I tried with dbo.People, but it is there at the bottom, easy to miss!

Comment: In a roundabout way you are right, see my answer below. Thanks!